# GCP Functions Node.js Huge Latency

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, serverless

We are running simple GCP Functions (pure, no Firebase, or any other layer added) that just handle HTTP requests using Node.js engine (previously version 8, now 10) and return some "simple JSON response". What we see is that sometimes (but not rarely) there is a huge latency when the request is "accepted by GCP" and before it gets to our function code. If I say huge I'm not speaking ms but units of seconds! And it is not a cold start (we have separate log messages on the global scope so we know when cold start occurs). Functions have currently 256 or 512 mb and run in close region.

We log at the very first line of the GCP function, for example:

[image: First latency example]

or

[image: Second latency example]

Does anyone also experience that? And is that normal that sometimes this delay may take up to 5s (or rarely even more)?
By the way, sometimes the same thing happens on the output side as well. So if unlucky, it may take up to 10s. Thanks in advance for any reply, no matter if you have or have not similar experience.

Answer (score 2):

All such problems I have seen have been related with cold start or it was not possible to prove that they are not related with code start.

This question could be even to broad to stackoverflow. We do not have any chance to reproduce it without example at least functions and number of the executions, however I will try to answer.

It seems that latency analyzes are done mainly on logs. I think you should try to use "Trace" functionality that is available in GCP ([direct link](https://console.cloud.google.com/traces) and [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/trace)). This should give you data to be able to track the issue.

Example i have used it on helloworld cloud function and was curl'ing it from bush script. It seems that over few hundreds of invocations there was one execution with latency 10 times greater than usually.

I hope it will help somehow :)!

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment :) It is, unfortunately, kind of usual and it is during fairly small but with sustainable frequency (like 1 request in few seconds) so that one function should be still hot.

For the cold start identification, I log at global level and it seems that information is correct.

I will try that trace! thanks for the tip

Comment: Hmm it turns out that it is maybe cold start! The thing is that when I log at global level, then that log is not related to any execution (I mistakenly assumed that it will be tied to the execution that initiated it). Will dig deeper in that.

Comment: Ok it seems that there are a lot more cold starts then I thought. But there is still sometimes kind of big latency between browser and Google infrastructure. For example in my browser I see that request took almost 7 seconds while in logs it took 3 seconds.